# how to get command argument in pageindexchangeing event for databinding

Tags: c#

1.This is my html code:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:GridView ID="reqparentgird" CssClass="prntgrd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="reqparentgird_RowCommand" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="reqparentgird_PageIndexChanging">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DAEBBA" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdhead" HeaderText="mainheader">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="namedatediv">
                                <asp:Label ID="namelbl" CssClass="grdnamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="datelbl" CssClass="grddatelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="grdmsgdiv">
                                <asp:Label ID="msglbl" CssClass="grdmsg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ReqInfo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="grddatelbl" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="addrlbl" CssClass="grdmsg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reqaddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div class="errdiv">
                                        <asp:Label ID="errorlbl" CssClass="errlbl" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grdtxtdiv">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="reqconvrstxt" CssClass="gridtxt" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="26" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="msgconttxt_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="reqconvrstxt" WatermarkText="Write your opinion here..">
                                        </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grdsndbtndiv">
                                        <asp:Button ID="grdsubbtn" CssClass="grdinsrtbtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ReqConversId") %>' CommandName="reqbooksget" />
                                    </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div class="inrgrdopenbtndiv">
                                        <asp:Button ID="grdconvrsbtn" CssClass="grdopnconvrbtn" runat="server" Text="Open all conversions" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ReqConversId") %>' CommandName="reqconversget" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inrgrddiv">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="reqchildgrd" CssClass="inrgrd" runat="server" Visible="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="reqchildgrd_PageIndexChanging1">
                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E4FFCA" />
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="inrgrdhead" HeaderText="User's comments.. of above book betails">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div class="namedatediv">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="inrlbl1" CssClass="grdnamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            <br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="inrlbl2" CssClass="grddatelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date", "{0:M-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="grdmsgdiv">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="inrlbl3" CssClass="grdmsg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ConvrsMessage") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                <div class="emptytemp">
                                                    At present we don't have any result's from your request....
                                                </div>
                                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFCEFF" />
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="grdhead"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div class="emptytemp">
                        At present we don't have any result's from your request....
                    </div>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFFC4" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

2.Bind my parent gridview in pageload:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    reqparentgird.DataSource = dataaccesslayer.getallreqedbks();
                    reqparentgird.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

3.Then my parent gridview have rowcommand events for execute insertcommand and binding innergridview when button click

```
    protected void reqparentgird_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
          if (e.CommandName == "reqbooksget")
        {
            string userid = Session["uid"].ToString();
            string username = Session["uname"].ToString();
            string reqconverid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            int rowindx = ((GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
            string reqbkmsg = ((TextBox)reqparentgird.Rows[rowindx].FindControl("reqconvrstxt")).Text;
            Label grderrlbl = (Label)reqparentgird.Rows[rowindx].FindControl("errorlbl");              
            dataaccesslayer reqconvrinsrtobj = new dataaccesslayer();
            reqconvrinsrtobj.reqbkconverinsrt(reqconverid, userid, username, reqbkmsg);
            grderrlbl.Text = "Your commant successfully placed....";

        }

        else if (e.CommandName == "reqconversget")
                {
                    string conversid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                    int rowindx =         ((GridViewRow)Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
                    GridView inrgrdview = (GridView)reqparentgird.Rows[rowindx].FindControl("reqchildgrd");

                        inrgrdview.DataSource = dataaccesslayer.getallreqconvermsg(conversid);
                        inrgrdview.DataBind();
                }
Binding innergridveiw by passing "conversid" as argument,converid value is assigned by command argument value i.e. `string conversid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

4.This is my getallreqconvermsg(conversid) method:

```
public static List<getreqbkconvrs> getallreqconvermsg(string conversid)
        {
            List<getreqbkconvrs> convrsreqbk = new List<getreqbkconvrs>();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mpdbcs"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand getreqbkconverscmd = new SqlCommand("getallreqconvers", conn);
                getreqbkconverscmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                getreqbkconverscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conversid", conversid);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reqconves = getreqbkconverscmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reqconves.Read())
                {
                    getreqbkconvrs reqbkconves = new getreqbkconvrs();
                    reqbkconves.Name = reqconves["Uname"].ToString();
                    reqbkconves.ConvrsMessage = reqconves["ConvrsMessage"].ToString();
                    reqbkconves.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reqconves["Date"]);
                    convrsreqbk.Add(reqbkconves);
                }
                return convrsreqbk;
            }
        }
```

5.Now i add pagging to parentgidview in aspx.cs this will work fine:

```
 protected void reqparentgird_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        reqparentgird.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        bindGridView();
    }
    private void bindGridView()
    {
        reqparentgird.DataSource = dataaccesslayer.getallreqedbks();
        reqparentgird.DataBind();
    }
```

6.Now i want to add pagging to innergridveiw so, i use pageindexchangeing event in this event requires databind again so i want to pass "conversid" as argument for databinding,but "conversid value comes from command argument" my question is how to get command argument in pageindexchanging event for calling method having single parameter.

```
    protected void reqchildgrd_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
            {
                GridView childgrd = (sender as GridView);            
                childgrd.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                string conversid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
         inrgrdview.DataSource = dataaccesslayer.getallreqconvermsg(conversid);
                inrgrdview.DataBind();
            }
```

7.This is the error getting when i add pagging to my innergirdview in pageindexchanging event:

```
  'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs'does not contain a definition for 
'commandargument' and no extension method 'commandargument' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.GridViewPageEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `string conversid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();` in multiple methods, you have to declare `conversid` as variable in your class.

Example:

```
     public class MyClass
      {

        private string lastConversid;

        ...

        else if (e.CommandName == "reqconversget")
                    {
                        this.lastConversid= e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        int rowindx = ((GridViewRow)Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
                        GridView inrgrdview = (GridView)reqparentgird.Rows[rowindx].FindControl("reqchildgrd");

        inrgrdview.DataSource = dataaccesslayer.getallreqconvermsg(this.lastConversid);
                            inrgrdview.DataBind();
                    }

        ....

      protected void reqchildgrd_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) {
        GridView childgrd = (sender as GridView);
        childgrd.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        inrgrdview.DataSource = dataaccesslayer.getallreqconvermsg(this.lastConversid);
        inrgrdview.DataBind();
      }

    }
```

Comment: I try this, this is the error in browser when i click "next" button in pagging innergridview.                Procedure or function 'getallreqconvers' expects parameter '@conversid', which was not supplied.

Comment: Listen, dont get me wrong, but do you actually know what you want? Furthermore, it comes to my mind that this is your homework.

Comment: your mentioned logic is right,but it's not getting value in pageindexchanging event.i try to put e.commandargument.tostring() value in session and call in pageindexchanging event it works fine and reach my  requirement,but i don't no this is right way or not.I am a student and i try to create a website,this code is a part of my website.Thankyou lokusking.